# how to find minimum value in a large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, min

I have a matrix `Z` e.g.

```
Z = randi(6, 20)
```

I want to find the minimum value from this matrix and display it using x,y coordinates.
I got it working once trying to work out the max value, but then replaced `max` with `min` in order to work out minimum value. The max works sometimes but the min has never worked, so I'm guessing something is incorrect. I need the min to work!

```
[x,y]=find(Z==max(max(Z)))
Z_max=Z(x,y))

[x,y]=find(Z==min(min(Z)))
Z_min=Z(x,y))
```

But I always get an error saying `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` When it worked, it gave me answer like this (which is exactly what i want):

```
x =

     5


y =

     3


Z_max =

    6
```

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the three-ouput version of `find`. Besides, that also returns the minimum (not only the indices):

```
[x y min_Z] = find(Z==min(Z(:)));
```

This will give several values if the minimum is achieved at several entries. If you only want the first, use:

```
[x y min_Z] = find(Z==min(Z(:)),1);
```

A possibly faster alternative, which gives only the first:

```
[min_Z k] = min(Z(:));
[x y] = ind2sub(size(Z),k);
```